# How to get each item from a list divisible by x number

Tags: python, list

Total noob here.  Been at it for three days now.  Been trying to solve this and looking for a hint.

The list contains a list of comma-separated numbers.   If the second number is evenly divisible by the first return TRUE in a list at the same index.  If it is not evenly divisible return false.  For example `[ "6,36" , "2,8" , "3,11" ]` you would answer `[ "True" , "True", "False" ]` because  36 is evenly divisible by 6, 8 is evenly divisible by 2 and 11 is NOT evenly divisible by 3.  Note the responses are case sensitive strings of either "True" or "False".

Here is an example list:

```
['21,42', '22,45', '11,23', '8,16']
```

I have had luck getting one index converted but I can't figure out how to loop through this

I have tried splitting the list and storing in a variable then using an if statement.

This works for the first index but obviously is not a loop so it won't solve them all.

```py
def solve(q):
    newlist = []
    if int(q[1]) % int(q[0]) == 0:
        newlist.append('True')
    else:
        newlist.append('False')
        return newlist
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to use a descriptive title. You might also want to add the attempted loops you wrote. See [ask] for more pointers. LMK when done and I'll reverse my downvote. (BTW I deleted my last comment cause I missed an important bit, sorry.)

Comment: Literally my first time on this site.  I will figure out the proper way to phrase my questions.  Thanks for the heads up.  I  knew I would catch some flack but you have to start somewhere I guess.

Comment: FYI, it's not so much flak as really important info that most people ignore (or just aren't aware of). Your question is already better than probably 90% on this site, but it could still benefit from more detail regarding what you tried; that's the kind of thing that helps people identify and understand your problem and start to determine solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? You will have to iterate through the list and since each element is a list, what you can do is to use the `.split()` method. Becareful of the indentations for the `return newlist`!

```
ls = ['21,42', '22,45', '11,23', '8,16']

def solve(q):
    newlist = []
    for i in q:
        first, second = i.split(',')
        print(second)
        if int(second) % int(first) == 0:
            newlist.append('True')
        else:
            newlist.append('False')
    return newlist

print(solve(ls))
# ['True', 'False', 'False', 'True']

# You can solve it using list comprehension too
newlist = [i.split(',') for i in ls]
outcome = [(int(i[1]) % int(i[0]) == 0) for i in newlist]
print(outcome)
```

Comment: Yep this did it.  I am very new at Python (third day), can you explain how the (first, second) part works?  This is great by the way.

Comment: @RitchieDeel You are basically iterating through the list with a `for` loop which accesses each elements in your list. In this case, each element is a `string` type hence what you'll have to do is to "split" them up by the separator of "," into their individual elements of 21 and 42 (for the first case), with the first split being 21 and second being 42.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I get it now.  As I said, I could do it in interactive mode by drilling down and getting one of them in the list but I could not figure out how to write a loop for this.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Applying basic [functional programming concepts](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/functional.html) like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) can sometimes provide significant improvements to the size and quality of your code. This problem can be solved very quickly if you think of it as applying a single function to each member of a list.

While I like list comprehensions, in this case, I think this is more readable:

```
def evaluate_pair(p):
    a, b = map(int, p.split(','))
    return str((b % a) == 0)
```

`p.split(',')` returns a collection, and `map` will call the function `int` against each element of that collection, the result being the returned values of `int(value)`. So `a` and `b` will now contain the integers you need to compare, allowing you to return the result of that comparison.

This solves one pair, like your initial code. To use this for a full list, you can use `map` again, this time to get the result of `evaluate_pair` against each pair string in your list.

Using this at the Python command line:

```
>>> initial = ['21,42', '22,45', '11,23', '8,16']
>>> tuple(map(evaluate_pair, initial))
('True', 'False', 'False', 'True')
>>> initial = [ "6,36" , "2,8" , "3,11" ]
>>> tuple(map(evaluate_pair, initial))
('True', 'True', 'False')
```

The use of `tuple` here is just to evaluate the map call for printing.

It's then easy to turn this into a function accepting a list:

```
def evaluate_list(l):
    return map(evaluate_pair, l)
```

Comment: This is a super slick way of doing this. I kept trying to use the map function initially but I wasn’t using it properly. Thanks for the response and excellent explanation.

Comment: You're welcome! I only started getting comfortable with it after I started working with Clojure. Now I tend to fall back to map for some things in Python as well.